# tcl set list of arrays produce duplicates

Tags: tcl

I'm producing a TCL procedure that will return a list of arrays of devices under a switch.  The definition is an XML file that is read.  The resulting lists of XML entries are parsed using a recursive procedure and the device attributes are placed in an array.

Each array is then placed in a list and reflected back to the caller.  My problem is that when I print out the list of devices, the last device added to the list is printed out each time.  The contents of the list is all duplicates.

Note:  I'm using the excellent proc, 'xml2list' that was found here.  I'm sorry, I forgot who submitted this.

The following code illustrates the problem:

```
source C:/src/tcl/xml2list.tcl

# Read and parse XML file
set fh [open C:/data/tcl/testfile.xml r]
set myxml [read $fh]
set mylist [xml2list $myxml]


array set mydevice {}

proc devicesByName { name thelist list_to_fill} {
        global mydevice
        global set found_sw 0

        upvar $list_to_fill device_arr
        foreach switch [lindex $thelist 2] {

            set atts [lindex $switch 1]
            if { [lindex $switch 0] == "Switch" } {
                if { $name == [lindex $atts 3] } {
                    set found_sw 1
                    puts "==== Found Switch: $name ===="
                } else {
                    set found_sw 0
                }
            } elseif { $found_sw == 1 && [string length [lindex $atts 3]] > 0 } {

                set mydevice(hdr) [lindex $switch 0]
                set mydevice(port) [lindex $atts 1]
                set mydevice(name) [lindex $atts 3]
                set mydevice(type) [lindex $atts 5]
                puts "Device Found: $mydevice(name)"
                set text [lindex $switch 2]
                set mydevice(ip) [lindex [lindex $text 0] 1]

                lappend device_arr mydevice
            }
            devicesByName $name $switch device_arr
         }
    }

    #--- Call proc here

    # set a local array var and send to the proc
    set device_arr {}
    devicesByName "Switch1" $mylist device_arr

    # read out the contents of the list of arrays
    for {set i 0} {$i<[llength $device_arr]} {incr i} {
        upvar #0 [lindex $device_arr $i] temp
        if {[array exists temp]} {
            puts "\[$i\] Device: $temp(name)-$temp(ip)"
        }
    }
```

The XML file is here:

```
<Topology>    
    <Switch ports="48" name="Switch1" ip="10.1.1.3">
        <Device port="1" name="RHEL53-Complete1" type="host">10.1.1.10</Device>
        <Device port="2" name="Windows-Complete1" type="host">10.1.2.11</Device>
   <Device port="3" name="Solaris-Complete1" type="host">10.1.2.12</Device>
    </Switch>
    <Switch ports="36" name="Switch2" ip="10.1.1.4">
        <Device port="1" name="Windows-Complete2" type="host">10.1.3.10</Device>
    </Switch>
    <Router ports="24" name="Router1" ip="10.1.1.2">
        <Device port="1" name="Switch1" type="switch">10.1.1.3</Device>
        <Device port="2" name="Switch2" type="switch">10.1.1.4</Device>
    </Router>
</Topology>
```

If my code blocks look bad, please excuse that.  I followed the directions as I read them, but it didn't look correct.  I could not fix it, so just posted anyway.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in tcl are not values. Therefore they don't behave like regular variables. They are in fact something special like filehandles or sockets.

You cannot assign an array to a list like that. Doing:

```
lappend device_arr mydevice
```

simply appends the string `"mydevice"` to the list `device_arr`. That string happens to be the name of a global variable so that string may be used later to access that global variable.

To build up a key-value data structure what you want is a [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm). You can think of a dict as a special list that has even numbers of elements in the format: `{key value key value}`. In fact, this data structure works even on very old versions of tcl before the introduction of `dict`s because the `foreach` loop in tcl can be used to process key-value pairs.

So what you want is to create a new `$mydevice` dict each loop and use `[dict set]` to assign the values.

Alternatively you can keep most of your code and change your lappend to:

```
lappend device_arr [array get mydevice]
```

This works because `[array get]` returns a key-value list which can be treated as a dict. You can later access the data using the `dict` command.

Comment: So basically, I'm accessing the name of the global var., 'mydevice' for each entry in the list.  Very tricky.  I will try using dict, but I'm not sure if the interpreter on the actual system can handle it.  It might be an older version.  If not, I'll have to use "array get"....thx...

Answer (score 2):

Array variables can't be used as values. To put the contents of one into a list element, send it to a proc, write it to a file etc, convert it to list form (key, value, key, value...) with `array get`.

```
lappend device_arr [array get mydevice]
```

To use it later, write the list back to an array with `array set`.

```
foreach device_l $device_arr {
  #array unset device
  array set device $device_l
  puts "$device(name)-$device(ip)"
}
```

Note that `array set` doesn't erase the old keys in the destination array, so if you use it in a loop and the key names aren't always the same, you need to clear the array every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can store this information in two ways using arrays . First is as a multi-dimensional array, in this case a three dimensional array and the second is a one dimensional array storing a list that can be converted easily to an array later for accessing data at a later time.

For the 3d array the key would be Switch Name,device_port,dataname you would change your erroneous temporary myDevice and lappend code to

```
  # attr is a list of { attributename1 value1  ... attributenameN valueN}
  array set temp $attr
  set port $temp(port)
  set text [lindex $switch 2]
  set ip [lindex [lindex $text 0] 1]
  # name already set to "Switch1" etc
  foreach f [array names temp ] {
      set device_arr($name,$port,$f) $temp($f)
  } 
  set device_arr($name,$port,ip) $ip
  array unset temp
```

this code results in the following ( when parray device_arr

```
parray device_arr

device_arr(Switch1,1,name) "Switch1"
device_arr(Switch1,1,port)  1
device_arr(Switch1,1,type) "RedHat .."  
device_arr(Switch1,1,ip) 10..
device_arr(Switch1,2,name) "Switch1"
device_arr(Switch1,2,port)  1
device_arr(Switch1,2,type) "RedHat .."  
device_arr(Switch1,2,ip) 10..
...
device_arr(Switch2,1,name) "Switch1"
device_arr(Switch2,1,port)  1
device_arr(Switch2,1,type) "Windows Complete"  
device_arr(Switch2,1,ip) 10..
....
```

to find ip of Switch1 port2 you would:

```
puts "the ip of Switch1 port 2 is $device_arr(Switch1,2,ip)"
```

Note lots of data duplication but you can access all data directly without having to go to an intermediate step to get to the data  as in the next scheme

```
  # attr is a list of { attributename1 value1  ... attributenameN valueN}
  set data $attr
  array set temp $attr
  set text [lindex $switch 2]
  set ip [lindex [lindex $text 0] 1]
  lappend data ip $ip 
   set key "$name,$temp(port)"
  # name already set to "Switch1" etc
  set device_arr($name,$port) $data
  array unset temp
```

doing a parray device_arr gives:

```
device_arr(Switch1,1) {  port "1" name "RHEL53-Complete1" type "host" ip 10.1.1.10 }
device_arr(Switch1,2) {  port "2" name "Windows-Complete1" type "host" ip 10.1.2.11}
....
```

to find the ip of swtich1 port 2 you would

```
  array set temp $device_array(Switch1,2)
   puts "ip of device 2 is $temp(ip)"
```